# Success and Failure functions in a store - Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I have a request which, on success, loops through each attribute of a JSON response and adds it to my `store`:

```
var request = Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'MCApp',
    jsonData: searchquery,
    params: {
        start: 0,
        limit: itemsPerPage
    },
    success: function(response) {
        mainresponse = response.responseText;
        if (mainresponse.length == 0) {
            alert('No results returned');
            return;
        }
        var decoded = Ext.decode(mainresponse);
        for (var i = 0; i < decoded.elements.length; i++) { // loop over decoded data
            var element = decoded.elements[i].element;
            var model = {};
            for (var x = 0; x < element.attributes.length; x++) { // loop over attributes
                var attribute = element.attributes[x];
                model[attribute.attrname] = attribute.attrvalue; // mapping element names & attributes
            }
            newstore.add(model); // implicitly cast data as Model
            models[i] = model;
        }
        newstore.loadRawData(models);
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert('Search Failed: Could not reach the server')
    }
});
```

I have now recreated the `request`above within my `store`. What I need to do is add these same success and failure functions.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'resultsetstore',
    autoLoad: false,
    pageSize: itemsPerPage,
    fields: [
        { name: 'id',          type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'name',        type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'description', type: 'auto' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajaxwithpayload', //customized proxy to read "jsonData" 
        url: 'MCApp',
        jsonData: searchquery,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'elements'
        }
        success: { /* success functions */ },
        failure: { /* failure functions */ }
    }

});
```

Here's what my response looks like:

```
{
   "elements":[
      {
         "element":{
            "name":"Element Name", 
            "id":"Element ID",
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "attrname":"id",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the ID"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"name",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the name"
               },
               //etc.
```

1) Is there any way to recreate these functions on my store?

2) Is decoding my response this way the best way to load my response into my store?

**EDIT**

I'm using the callback function when I load the store:

```
store.load({
    params: { start: 0, limit: itemsPerPage },
    callback: function(options, success, response, records) {
        if (success) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }           
    }
});
```

However, I'm getting an `undefined` in my alert, and it's telling me there are 0 records loaded. But when I look at my response in Firebug I see my JSON string returned just fine.

Comment: why not look at the examples on their website? they have this covered.

Comment: Okay I admit I did get a bit lazy here. Could this be done with `callback`?

Comment: If you're not sure what a function returns you can do a `console.log(arguments)` => it 'll log you the array of all the arguments, the order of the arguments was wrong. :) (or you could check the documentation ofcourse ;) )

Comment: Hey @VDP, have another! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481633/grid-not-displaying-all-records-ext-js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Error handling in stores**

You can listen for the [exception-event](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-event-exception) on the proxy to capture all the store errors.
And for success on the store [load-event](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-load)

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'resultsetstore',
    autoLoad: false,
    pageSize: itemsPerPage,
    fields: [
        { name: 'id',          type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'name',        type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'description', type: 'auto' }
    ],
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
            if (successfull) {
                alert('success');
            }
        }
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajaxwithpayload', //customized proxy to read "jsonData" 
        url: 'MCApp',
        jsonData: searchquery,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'elements'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                alert('exception');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

or in the load call itself:

```
store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

or if you use sync (for saving removed, modified,...)

```
store.sync({
    callback: function(batch, options) {
        // ...
    },
    success: function(batch, options) {
        // ...
    },
    failure: function(batch, options) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I had a few syntax errors on my `store.load({})` at first, I think it was the order of it's parameters, but now it works wonders. Thanks again @VDP!

Comment: How do it in add, update or delete actions ?